# Add VirtualizedScrollPane to InlineCssTextArea or any related GenericStyledArea by Scene Builder

Tags: javafx, textarea, scenebuilder, scrollpane

how can I add the scroll abiltiy with VirtualizedScrollPane (explained in [GenericStyledArea-#Adding Scrollbars to the Area](https://fxmisc.github.io/richtext/javadoc/0.9.0/org/fxmisc/richtext/GenericStyledArea.html)) for InlineCssTextArea in JavaFx Scene Builder? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround.Editing the FXML-file by hand.
Like the [RichtTextFX-Issue](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/issues/798) descriped:

```
<VirtualizedScrollPane
    fx:id="sourceContainerTextScreenVirtualizedScrollPane" 
    layoutX="265.0" 
    layoutY="98.0">
  <content> 
    <InlineCssTextArea 
        fx:id="theICA" 
        layoutX="0.0" 
        layoutY="0.0" 
        onKeyReleased="#handler" 
        onMouseReleased="handelrer2" 
        prefHeight="277.0" 
        prefWidth="674.0" 
        wrapText="true"/> 
  </content> 
</VirtualizedScrollPane>
```

but add also a

```
@FXML private VirtualizedScrollPane<InlineCssTextArea> sourceContainerTextScreenVirtualizedScrollPane;
```

to your controller, if you want to controll it. Otherwise in my code it also works without controller declaration.
I hope this will help you till it is included into the Scene Builder.